# How do I find the test device id for the ti.admob module for an iOS appcelerator project

Tags: ios, admob, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have an iOS mobile app in appcelerator titanium which is using the Ti.Admob module. When running in the simultaor the adverts are there, but when debugging on the device it is blank.

Looking at the documentation I should be able to get the test device id from the console.log, and add it to my testDevices array in the createView function, but I can't find the test device id anywhere.

Seems abolutely bonkers, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the Id in question is the MD5 hash of the advertising identifier for your phone. I downloaded an app called [The Identifiers](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/the-identifiers/id564618183?mt=8) which gives you all the information you need.

Add the MD5 hash of the advertising identifier to the testDevices array in the createView method and you will then see ads in your app.

```
var ad1 = Admob.createView({
             height: 50,
             top: 0,
             debugEnabled: true, // If enabled, a dummy value for `adUnitId` will be used to test
             adType: Admob.AD_TYPE_BANNER,
             adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-000000xxxxxxxxxx/8204200000', // You can get your own at http: //www.admob.com/
             adBackgroundColor: 'black',
             testDevices: [Admob.SIMULATOR_ID,'xxxc8xx0xxxccxxb4a12cxxxxxxxxxxx'], // You can get your device's id by looking in the console log
              dateOfBirth: new Date(1985, 10, 1, 12, 1, 1),
              gender: Admob.GENDER_MALE, // GENDER_MALE or GENDER_FEMALE default: undefined
             contentURL: 'https://admob.com', // URL string for a webpage whose content matches the app content.
             requestAgent: 'Titanium Mobile App', // String that identifies the ad request's origin.
    extras: {
       'version': 1.0,
       'name': 'Eyespy'
    }, // Object of additional infos
    tagForChildDirectedTreatment: false, // http:///business.ftc.gov/privacy-and-security/childrens-privacy for more infos
     keywords: ['keyword1', 'keyword2']
     });

    $.adview.add(ad1);
```